# While template deduction, is it possible to detect if a consteval function could be run

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, consteval

Let's say we have a `consteval` function or a trivial struct with `consteval` construnctor, which only accept some of the values:

```
struct A
{
    consteval A(int a)
    {
        // compile error if a < 0
        if (a < 0)
            throw "error";
    }
};
```

Is there any way to detect if a non-type template parameter of int could be accepted by such a constructor? I have tried the following code but failed.

```
template <int a> concept accepted_by_A = requires() {A(a);};

int main()
{
    std::cout << accepted_by_A<-1> << std::endl; // output 1 (true)
}
```

Comment: This seems impossible since it is a hard error. Why not just `template <int a> concept accepted_by_A = a >= 0;`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Primarily, I want to write a concept to detect whether a type could be accepted by fmt::format with specific format string form {fmt} library. For example, `int a; fmt::format("{}", a);` is OK, but both `int* p; fmt::format("{}", p);` and `int a; fmt::format("{:abc}", a);` will give an error at compile time. To simplify the question about fmt, I think I should solve this question first.

Comment: If it compiles it is accepted. consteval is only evaluated at compile time and won't result in "runtime" code so in that sense it cannot be run. (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval). So you cannot make calls to consteval function from main! (If you want both compiletime and runtime versions use constexpr)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since a call to a `constexpr` (or `consteval`) function that throws is not a constant expression, you can detect this:

```
template<int I> concept accepted_by_A=
  requires() {typename std::type_identity_t<int[(A(I),1)]>;};

static_assert(accepted_by_A<1>);
static_assert(!accepted_by_A<-1>);
```

It's also possible to use SFINAE (which would allow it to work with `constexpr` in previous language versions):

```
template<int,class=void> struct test : std::false_type {};
template<int I> struct test<I,decltype(void((int(*)[(A(I),1)])nullptr))> : std::true_type {};

static_assert(test<1>());
static_assert(!test<-1>());
```

An alternate specialization

```
template<int I> struct test<I,typename voided<int[(A(I),1)]>::type> : std::true_type {};
```

seems like it ought to work but doesn't; substitution of non-type template arguments is weird in some cases.

Comment: GREAT answer! BTW, the alternative specialization could not be used maybe because of something about the template parameter pack, which is use by `std::void_t`. Following code works well: `template<int I> struct test<I, typename my_void_t<decltype(void((int(*)[(A(I),1)])nullptr))>::type> : std::true_type {};`, and `my_void_t` is defined as `template <typename T> struct void_t {using type = void;};`